# XML Schema File that validates my XML File

Tags: xml, xsd

I just want to know if my schema file is correct:

XML File:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xs:books xmlns="http://www.w3.com/1999/XML/prjXMLValidation"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/prjXMLValidation"
      xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="collection.xsd">
   <xs:book title="A Lesson Before Dying" author="Ernest J. Gaines" version="1">
<xs:stars>
     5
    </xs:stars>
    <xs:description>
  This is a story about a young man that was wrongly
  accused of killing a white man in the south at a time
  when blacks were not given the same rights as whites.
  This is the story of how Jefferson becomes a man.
    </xs:description>
<xs:thoughts>
    Great book!
</xs:thoughts>
  </xs:book>
</xs:books>
```

Here is my XSD File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/prjXMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="books">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="book">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="stars">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                  <xs:element ref="1" />
                  <xs:element ref="2" />
                  <xs:element ref="3" />
                  <xs:element ref="4" />
                  <xs:element ref="5" />
                </xs:choice>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="thoughts" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          <xs:attribute name="author" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element> 
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element> 
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Well, you may want to include the XSD file `collection.xsd` ... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall your structures look OK. Your actual XML document could be indented more neatly, but it's OK.

I would recommend that you change your `stars` element to have an attribute. Using the PCDATA space is not a great place to put a numeric value.... Actually, I would recommend adding a `stars` attribute to the `thoughts` element (seems like a logical place to put it)....

```
<xs:thoughts stars="5" >
    Great book!
</xs:thoughts>
```

This brings up the validation of the stars value too.... you have broken references in your XSD:

```
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
              <xs:element ref="1" />
              <xs:element ref="2" />
              <xs:element ref="3" />
              <xs:element ref="4" />
              <xs:element ref="5" />
            </xs:choice>
          </xs:complexType>
```

The references `1` .... `5` are not declared. This is a problem. But, you should be using references (just not those ones....). You should be separating out your XSD types and then merging them up in complex-types with `ref` references. You should also be declaring the types outside of their usage... which makes things easier to manage.

Consider the following (which changes the stars validation, and location).

```
<xs:simpleType name="startype">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="[1-5]"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

.....
<xs:element name="thoughts">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="stars" type="startype" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Sorry about the formatting of my XML file. It was not like that originally, but when I put my code into the site it refused to format correctly. At least my XSD turned out the way I made it. And thank you for your advice!